# SAPI5 speaking XML

Tags: c#, vb.net, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, speechsynthesizer

I would like to use the "SpeechSynthesizer" to speak a text, but this text includes some XML tags.
Using the old COM object, I used

```
 S5Voice.Speak uString, SVSFDefault Or SVSFIsXML
```

However, there is no overloaded function in SpeechSynthesizer that I could use to define that the text is an XML string.

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeakSsml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakssml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should do the trick.  Otherwise, you're going to have to strip the tags before sending it to the synthesis engine.